# Реализация стен в игре

Tags: python, алгоритм, pygame

Сейчас я делаю игру на Python и Pygame, и я застрял на том, как правильно обрабатывать столкновение игрока со стенами. Это 2Д РПГшка с видом сверху

Я могу получить список стен, с которыми игрок сталкивается через `pygame.spritecollide()` и могу узнать все прямоугольники пересечения через `player.rect.clip(wall.rect)`. Но я не знаю, что с этим делать.

У меня были такие идеи:

1. Выталкивать игрока в направлении, противоположном его скорости. Но тогда, если мы, например, будем двигаться вправо и вниз, и нам встретится стена справа, то мы будем оставаться на одном месте, потому что мы должны быть вытолкнуты только влево, но не вверх.
2. Вторая — реализовать движение по диагонали как по одному шагу в две стороны, вверх и вправо, к примеру. Но тогда имеет значение, двигаем ли мы игрока вправо или вверх вначале, и это делает двойственные ситуации.

Не знаю, какой алгоритм нужно реализовать, чтобы грамотно сделать коллизию со стенами.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно сначала изменить координату игрока например по y на 10 пикселей затем, проверить сталкивается ли он с чем-нибудь. Если сталкивается, то из y координаты вычесть обратно 10 пикселей. Затем сделать также с x координатой. Пример:

```
link.rect.y += link.y_speed
    if self.rect.colliderect(stone.hitbox):
        #  if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, walls):
        link.rect.y -= link.y_speed
    link.rect.x += link.x_speed
    if self.rect.colliderect(stone.hitbox):
        # if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, walls):
        link.rect.x -= link.x_speed
```

Answer (score 0):

Движущийся объект имеет вектор скорости `V=(vx, vy)`

Стена имеет вектор нормали (перпендикуляр к ней) `N = (nx, ny)`

После отражения от этой стены вектор скорости объекта будет

```
dot = vx * nx + vy * ny //скалярное произведение

newV_x = vx - 2 * dot * nx
newV_y = vy - 2 * dot * ny
```